# How to make an image show when a box is hovered over?

Tags: html, css, class

So i've got a bit of a problem. I'm trying to have an image show when your mouse hovers over a box. However the image isn't the box the image is separate. I also need it on the left hand side. So is it possible to call an image to show itself when something else is being activated?

Here's the box thats going to be hovered over.

```
    li.rightbox2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    float: center;
    width:430px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin:0px;
    opacity: 0.2;

    }
    li.rightbox2:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity: 1.0;
        }

and here is where i want the image

    li.leftbox {
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:478px;
    height:630px;
    border:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
    }
```

<>
    So I need to be able to call the image in the li.rightbox css class?
    Is this possible? Is it possible to do without Javascript?

```
The HTML is:

    <!DOCTYPE html> 

<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="styleSheet" type="text/css" href="CSS\style.css"/>   

        <title> GTM HOME </title>

</head>

<body>

    <nav> 
        <ul>
            <li class="leftbox"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="rightbox1"><a href="lineup.html">LINEUP</a></li>
            <li class="rightbox2"><a href="event-info.html">EVENT INFO</a></li>
            <li class="rightmiddle"><a href="tickets.html">TICKET</a></li>
            <li class="rightlower"><a href="enquiries.html">ENQUIRIES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <main>
    <img class="mainm" src="images\lineupp.jpg"/>

    </main>

    <video id="backgroundvid" autoplay loop poster>
        <source src="videos\backgroundvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: We have to see your HTML to be able to help you

Comment: You can also make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this :

The activator :

```
<div onMouseOver="showImage()" onMouseOut="hideImage()">...</div>
```

The image container

```
<div id="imgDiv"></div>
```

then :

```
<script>
    showImage() {
        document.getElementById("imgDiv").innerHTML='<img src="path/to/img" alt="img" \>';
    }
    hideImage() {
        document.getElementById("imgDiv").innerHTML='';
    }
</script>
```

Without Javascript, maybe this can solve your problem, but it is really less flexible : [CSS - Rollover one element, and make another element visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776109/css-rollover-one-element-and-make-another-element-visible)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to apply a class to the `.leftbox` then use that to display the image.

```js
$('li.rightbox2').hover(function() {
    $('li.leftbox').toggleClass('hovered');
});
```

```css
li.rightbox2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    float: center;
    width:430px;
    height:200px;
    border:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin:0px;
    opacity: 0.2;
}
li.rightbox2:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
li.leftbox {
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:478px;
    height:630px;
    border:2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0px;
}
li.leftbox.hovered {
    background: url(image-folder/image.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;    
}
```